# "click" doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

This is the javascript I use for my burger navigation. My code works perfectly on Chrome, but it doesn't works on my iPhone. I think it has to do with the "click" but i'm not sure.

I tried using "touchend" instead of click but that doesn't work either.

This is my code:

```
onload = function() {
    var hetMenu = document.querySelector("body > header nav");
    hetMenu.addEventListener("click", menuToggle);
}

function menuToggle() {
    var deBody = document.querySelector("body");
    deBody.classList.toggle("navigatie");
    console.log(deBody.classList);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if `menuToggle` function is called after the click? Is it possible that on small screen something covers the element click event is attached to?

Comment: No I think that's not it. When I downsize my Chrome screen to mobile format it works just fine.

Comment: Check if: **1.** `menuToggle` is being called after click, **2.** manually add `navigate` class to your `body` element and see if that works on the device

Answer (score 1):

Use both click and touchstart events.

See: [onClick not working on mobile (touch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015908/onclick-not-working-on-mobile-touch)

It's jQuery but same events can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'touchstart' with jquery.

$('#button1').on('touchstart click', function(){ /* code here */ });