# Button not working on Mobile Devices but works on PC bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a bootstrap button that has a link inside.  Which looks like this:

[image]

When you hover on it:

[image]

This is the code inside the button:

```
 <div class="s-8"><button type="button" onClick="javascript:location.href = 'administration.php';">Administration</button></div>
```

The logout button:

```
<div class="s-4"><button type="button" onClick="javascript:location.href = 'logout.php';">Logout</button></div>
```

This button works fine on the PC(IE, SAFARI, FireFox, Chrome, Opera) browser(takes me to the administration page, but it doesn't work on the Mobile devices.

I did the same thing for the logout button, and it works fine on PC and Mobile Devices. I am now puzzled.

Comment: what's the browser you use on mobile?

Comment: [**Links aren't buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/) & *vice versa*

Comment: @MaximMai   I am using the default android browser

Comment: @Paulie_D What I don't understand is the inconsistency. That the logout button works but I used the same code

Comment: Is the logout button a link? Seems unlikely.

Comment: @Paulie_D  I will attach the code for it

Comment: @kya I have tried your code on my android phone with default android browser. it's work correctly

Comment: @mdemir Thanks. Then the issue must be with the hosting server and not the code itself. Thanks

Comment: if you can share demo link. maybe I can help you.

Comment: Don't put clickable elements in clickable elements. It will break with some browsers and it does not follow HTML 5 standards.

Comment: @mdemir I am trying to figure out where to put a demo for you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue may be that you're using the onClick event which won't register on a mobile device (as you don't click - you tap).

This answer explains how to use the "touchstart" event which will work on a mobile.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22015946/2619909

Answer (score 5):

I know this might be a weird answer. But in some cases mobile clickevents dont work unless you put the style: cursor:pointer; to your button.

Mobile clickEvents are handled very differently, the first "click" or "tap" might be interpreted as a HOVER instead of the click which you are looking for.

So try setting the CSS style of the button to : cursor:pointer;

Comment: Note that this generally only applies to iOS, and there are other possible workarounds; see http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Safari_Mobile

Comment: @JSMorgan can you prepare a fiddle where it's reproducable?

Comment: Upvoted, this worked for me on Android Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

unfortunately neither setting `cursor:pointer;` nor adding a `touchstart` event listener

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button_id').on('click touchstart', function() {
    window.location.href = "/url";
  });
});
```

as @noa-dev and @GitPauls suggested worked for me. for reference I tested on my phone7 (ios11.4 and safari)

**working solution:** I set the `z-index` of the button to a large positive number and the button now works.

```
#button_id{
  z-index: 99;
}
```

*solution found thanks to Daniel Acree* https://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/3258-buttons-not-clickable-on-iphone. I don't know if this generalizes to all iphone/mobile devices.