# button click not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a form that has 2 buttons on the botton.

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="submit-button-mobile">Submit</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <a href="/how_to_book.php">
        <div class="how-to-book-button-mobile">
            How to book?
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

originaly i had `onclick="send_message();"` on the `submit-button-mobile` (which worked for desktop but not on mobile. Also the  tag was also not clickable on mobile.

I've searched here and found this answer to make it work on mobile

```
        $('.submit-button-mobile').on('click touchstart', send_message);
        $('.how-to-book-button-mobile').on('click touchstart', function() {
            window.location.href = "/how_to_book.php";
        });
```

And still have the same problem, unclickable on mobile (tried on chrome developer tools with mobile view and tried on iphone and android).

send_message() is in another .js file included at the top of file.
It looks like this

```
function send_message()
        {
            var a=document.forms["Form"]["name"].value;
            var b=document.forms["Form"]["email"].value;
            var c=document.forms["Form"]["message"].value;
            var d=document.forms["Form"]["surname"].value;

            document.getElementById("contact_message").innerHTML = "Sending your message... Please wait.";

            loadXMLDoc(a, b, c, d);
        }


        //pomocna funkcija za validaciju emaila
        function validateEmail(email) {
            var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
            return re.test(email);
        }

        //funkcija za slanje emaila
        function loadXMLDoc(name, mail, message, surname)
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("contact_message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("contact_message2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }

            // xmlhttp.open("GET","send_enquiry.php",true);
            xmlhttp.open("POST","send_enquiry.php",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send("name=" + name + "&email=" + mail + "&message=" + message + "&surname=" + surname);

            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

Comment: definition for `send_message`?

Comment: Even control is not coming over there??

Comment: added the send_message function in the original post. Even the link is not working. What am i doing wrong? The same function is working properly on desktop view when i call it with onclick tag inside the div of the button.

Comment: Can you trace it with alerts after and before the document is ready on the page? And also trace it in the `click touchstart` whether the event is fired or not..

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by traceing it with alerts. But i've put breakpoints in file where send_message() is and it doesn't go till that part when i click on the button. But when i do it in desktop the breakpoint is working.

Comment: Alerts tracing/console tracing.. Put console.log("hello"); or an alert() inside the click handler and inside the function, so you can see what is actually not working.

Comment: Also, use the long syntax for handler and don't forget brackets: .on("click",  function(){ console.log("hi"); sendmessage(); });

Comment: if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 
 if ('ontouchend' in document || (/windows phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()))){
    EventType = (document.ontouchstart!==null)? 'click' : 'touchend';
  }
}
use this code for define event for desktop and mobile and used EventType instead of click or tuchstart and write properly event on button like body .on EventType  the selector and function

Comment: the button is not clickable (i guess that is due to page layout (positioning:absolute) I'll try changing that and get back.

Comment: That was the problem, there way another div going over the buttons. I've put z-index a higher number on the buttons and it's working now even with the original option (inline onclick="send_message()") Sorry for bothering you. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to write click function in the same file where you have defined the `send_message()` definition as well as click definition should be inside `document.ready()` function. First check whether you are getting alert or not on click of div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.how-to-book-button-mobile').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
           alert("how-to-book-button-mobile");
});
$('.submit-button-mobile').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           alert("submit");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="submit-button-mobile">Submit</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="how-to-book-button-mobile">
            How to book?
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015908/onclick-not-working-on-mobile-touch/22015946#22015946) also might help you.

Comment: It was only the problem of not being able to click on the button (there was an overlay over it which i didn't notice). Thank you for the help though

Comment: Thanks for sharing your soln. This also might help someone. Feels great when you solve your own problem.