# Copy current url button - Javascript

Tags: javascript

okay it might be something simple or completely wrong however I'm trying to create a button to copy current URL to clipboard, this is what I currently have, I'm not too familiar with javascript so this is from a few sources mixed together and hoping for the best.

```
<button onclick="CopyLink()">Click me</button>
<script>
function CopyLink() {
window.clipboardData.setData("Text", location.href);
}
</script>
```

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/400212/4446383

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the function `copyTextToClipboard` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/1612562), you can copy the link on a button click like so:

```js
function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");

  //
  // *** This styling is an extra step which is likely not required. ***
  //
  // Why is it here? To ensure:
  // 1. the element is able to have focus and selection.
  // 2. if element was to flash render it has minimal visual impact.
  // 3. less flakyness with selection and copying which **might** occur if
  //    the textarea element is not visible.
  //
  // The likelihood is the element won't even render, not even a flash,
  // so some of these are just precautions. However in IE the element
  // is visible whilst the popup box asking the user for permission for
  // the web page to copy to the clipboard.
  //

  // Place in top-left corner of screen regardless of scroll position.
  textArea.style.position = 'fixed';
  textArea.style.top = 0;
  textArea.style.left = 0;

  // Ensure it has a small width and height. Setting to 1px / 1em
  // doesn't work as this gives a negative w/h on some browsers.
  textArea.style.width = '2em';
  textArea.style.height = '2em';

  // We don't need padding, reducing the size if it does flash render.
  textArea.style.padding = 0;

  // Clean up any borders.
  textArea.style.border = 'none';
  textArea.style.outline = 'none';
  textArea.style.boxShadow = 'none';

  // Avoid flash of white box if rendered for any reason.
  textArea.style.background = 'transparent';


  textArea.value = text;

  document.body.appendChild(textArea);

  textArea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }

  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}

function CopyLink() {
  copyTextToClipboard(location.href);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="CopyLink()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: @Prefix maybe `touchstart` instead of `onclick`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015908/onclick-not-working-on-mobile-touch