# javascript mobile view chrome click not working

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).off("click", ".switch_cities").on("click", ".switch_cities", function(e) { 
        alert('uuuu');
        e.preventDefault();
        var r = $("#from").val(),
            t = $("#to").val();
        ("" != r || "" != t) && ($("#from").val(t), $("#to").val(r))
    })
```

The above code is used to switch cities in two text boxes
it works in Firefox and chrome but it doesn't work in Various mobile views of chrome

Comment: Can you try removing e.preventDefault(); and use return false; at the end of the on click event

Comment: please define 'Various mobile views of chrome' and provide some html or working code

Comment: responsive,galaxy s5 ,nexus 5x, u can check in inspect element , the tab near to elements tab

Comment: Created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sameer_ngl/95jrumcq/4/ and checked all the above cases. working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript you use the on then click, technically you are not using click on a mobile phone.

You can try the accepted answer in the following link which has the same problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22015946/2619909

Comment: Can you give me the link? I'm starting to think that this may be cause by the OS of the phone having different API's. But if you have same OS in different phones, I'll try to do more research.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using click, use tap event handlers. Judging by your above snippet you seem to use jQuery. jQuery has awesome event handlers, use [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_touch.asp) link to see how to utilize jQuery `tap` events.

Bonus point of using `tap` is they also seem to work on desktop browsers, as seen in the demo on the above link. Cheers!