# Onclick download button to an image for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I need to add a download button to an image in a website that is a mobile site. I looked other related questions and all of that are for PC browsers. I need an answer to support mobile browsers.

I used [HTML `<a>` download Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_a_download.asp)

But it's not supported in mobile browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick not working on mobile (touch)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015908/onclick-not-working-on-mobile-touch)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<a href="/path/to/image" download="myimage"><img src="/path/to/image" /></a>
```

Comment: I tried this one as i informed in my question. i need a code that support in a mobile browsers. your code working in computer browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Jquery if Html Failed.....Html Code

```
 <div id="imageDiv"><img src="ImageLink" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
 <a href="#" onclick="Download_Image(this)" download>Click here to download image</a>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
   function Download_Image(element)
   {
     debugger;
     var mydiv =$("#imageDiv");
     var Image=mydiv[0].children;
     mydiv.download=Image[0].src;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm using a range of images and i need a solution that can be added to a  loop.

Comment: You can do that by adding same Class to your Div