# Close the sidebar menu when click on body in mobile version

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code working perfectly for desktop version. It closes the sidenav div when clicked outside after opening it (in the body).

How should I make it work in the mobile version? It doesn't seem to recognize the javascript. Could someone help?

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}

$('body').on('click', function(){
  if( parseInt( $('#mySidenav').css('width') ) > 0 ){
    closeNav();
  }
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
<p>Click on the body area here to close the menu after opening it. However,
 it doesn't work on mobile version. </p>
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22015946/1339516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding `touchstart` got it to work on mobile :)

```
$('body').on('click touchstart', function(){
  if( parseInt( $('#mySidenav').css('width') ) > 0 ){
    closeNav();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this and let me know if it works for you

```
function openNav() {
    console.log("open");
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}


document.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if( parseInt( $('#mySidenav').css('width') ) > 0 ){
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
});
```

Comment: As mentioned; this works only on the desktop and not on the mobile. I have fixed it by adding `touchstart` in the answer. Thank you so much :)