# Element is selectable only on specific place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, devise, responsive-design

I have the following hiperlink

```
<a href="courses.html"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up icon_1" style="font-size: 20px; transition: color 0.2s ease 0s, border-color 0.2s ease 0s, background-color 0.2s ease 0s; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; line-height: 20px; border-width: 0px 2px 0px 0px; margin: 0px; padding:0px 10px 0 0; letter-spacing: 0px;"></i>Test Text</a>
```

As it can be see it point to another one page inside my app. The problem is on "mobile version of the site - responsive one" - redirect is happen only if the user click in begin of the "button". If for example i click between Test and Text or at the end of Text word redirect is not happen at all.

[image]

I tried to add an Id and capture the click event with Jquery and remove the icon that the element has on the photo:

```
<a id="TestClick" href="courses">Test Text</a>

$("#TestClick").click(function () {
    console.log("BLA BALDS:LAD:LA")
});
```

No luck again the element has to be click at the begin of the text in order to detect the click event

[image]

I tried last code with and without href="courses" inside "a" tag. I want to mention that the problem is only happen when the page is used on mobile device and inside Google Chrome`s toggle devise tool turn on. I want to fix this because i really annoying for the user to click more then once on some "button"

Comment: Can you reproduce at a site like JSBin or something? I think some code is missing because, for example, `#TestClickCourses` isn't associated with any HTML you've posted. If you can reproduce on JSBin or similar we can help better. If not, I might take a look that: 1. there's not any elements overlapping your element making it unclickable because the overlapping element is blocking or 2. you're trying to select a child element to be the clickable element and you want a parent

Comment: https://jsbin.com/wigisexapa/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 0):

Put `&nbsp;` in place of each space character. something like this:

`<a id="TestClick" href="courses">Test&nbsp;Text</a>`

Comment: put your code in span tag like this `<span>Test&nbsp;Text</span>` and try again.

Comment: <a id="TestClickCourses"><span>Test&nbsp;Text</span></a>  No luck again. I also tried  <a id="TestClickCourses"><span>Test&nbsp;Text&nbsp;</span></a> but it didnt work also. Why this element is acting like this Oo

Comment: try this jQuery code:
`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('TestClickCourses').click(function(){
   window.location.replace('/courses.html');
});
});`

Comment: let me know if you are using a css framework like bootstrap.

Comment: Again is only trigger at the begin on the text(like i shown on the photos).Why this is happen only on mobile devices ? Yes im using bootstrap.

Comment: i think it's a problem with bootstrap because i had the same problem. 
 i think on this page you can find good answers for solve your problem.
follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015908/onclick-not-working-on-mobile-touch/22015946#22015946)

Comment: someone proposes to use `touchstart` event with `.on()` jQuery method

Comment: good luck and let me know if you have success in resolving your problem.