# my button isn't working on mobile device but it does works on the mobile simulator on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html

trying to get my burger icon to show the mobile menu from hidden to block with "display", code works on desktop with chrome simulator but not on the actual mobile device.
my website is www.rikuzit.co.il

```
window.onclick = function(event){
    var burger = document.getElementById("burgerIcon");
    var mobileMenu = document.getElementById("mobileMenu");


if(event.target == burger){
    alert("burger was pressed");
        console.log(event.target);
        mobileMenu.style.display = "block"; 
    } else {    
        alert("clicked outside burger");
        console.log(event.target);
        mobileMenu.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

i expect that when the button is tapped the menu should appear.

Comment: It works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22015946/10221765), it's better to use `touchstart` for mobile devices:

```
window.ontouchstart = function(event){
    var burger = document.getElementById("burgerIcon");
    var mobileMenu = document.getElementById("mobileMenu");


if(event.target == burger){
    alert("burger was pressed");
        console.log(event.target);
        mobileMenu.style.display = "block"; 
    } else {    
        alert("clicked outside burger");
        console.log(event.target);
        mobileMenu.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, it worked but now, how can i check if the user tapped outside the mobileMenu so to close it? 
i've tried the same with "window" 

$(window).on('click touchstart', function() {
        $('#mobileMenu').css('display','none');

how can i check "if the user tapped anything but the 'mobile menu'"?  is there something like " != "?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer - you don't need jQuery. Simply replace `onclick` with `ontouchstart` and it will work. I will edit my answer.

Comment: My new problem is that when the "mobileMenu" appears and i tap on it, the "else" statement get's into action, so i tried to do if(event.target == burger || event.target == mobileMenu){mobileMenu.style.display = "block";}  else { display:none};, i it did not work, do you have any ideas about how to make the mobile stay in "display:block" when i tap it? and why " || event.target == mobileMenu"  do not work?

Comment: ok i figured out that when i click the "mobileMenu" sometimes it's a "li" being selected, and sometimes it's "a", only when i click on the border of the div(mobileMenu) the event is the div being touched.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
window.onclick = eventHandler
window.ontouch = eventHandler


function eventHandler(event){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(copied Shubham Chaudhary's answer)
i hope this should work

```
window.onclick = eventHandler
window.ontouch = eventHandler


function eventHandler(event){
...
}
```