# how to change or add click function js/css for mobile use

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I'm looking to add the ability to use this website on mobile by being clickable as opposed to mouseenter/mouseleave that works well on computers.

https://codepen.io/chabco/pen/YoyVdO

I've tried using combinations of :active in css and 'click' in js so far in vain. I think it's still right but there is something else that I need to change and I'm not sure what else it is.

```js
page.forEach(function(thePage){
    thePage.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        page[0].classList.remove('hoverin');
        thePage.classList.add('hoverin');
    });
    thePage.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        thePage.classList.remove('hoverin');
        page[0].classList.add('hoverin');
    });
});
```

```css
.page:nth-child(1):hover {
    grid-column: 1 / span 8;
}
```

While on mobile view mode in chrome, I thought I'd be able to click on the next page and obtain the same results as hover (showing the next page and its contents).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. So you want to use `click` instead of `mouseenter`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015908/onclick-not-working-on-mobile-touch

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use for mobile is `touchstart` and `touchend`:

```
thePage.addEventListener('click touchstart', function() {});
thePage.addEventListener('click touchend', function() {});
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events