# Cannot click on div from mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

```js
function checkButton(element) {
  var cb = $(element).find("input:checkbox");

  if (!$(cb).prop('checked')) {
    $(cb).prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $(cb).prop('checked', false);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form method="post" action="">
  <div class="list-group" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <div class="list-dark list-group-item" onclick="checkButton(this)">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox float-right">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" style="cursor: pointer;" />
      </div>
      <a href="">SAS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="list-dark list-group-item" onclick="checkButton(this)">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox float-right">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" style="cursor: pointer;" />
      </div>
      <a href="">SES</a>
    </div>
    <div class="list-dark list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</div>
    <div class="list-dark list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</div>
    <div class="list-dark list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary float-right">Save</button>
</form>
```

I'm making a list with a checkbox for the rows. From mobile, I cannot click on the list elements but on the pc I can. I don't know how to fix this. I tried to replace divs with ul/li but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify "from mobile": Android or iPhone? Which mobile browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick not working on mobile (touch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015908/onclick-not-working-on-mobile-touch)

Comment: @JDB On Android with Brave browser. 
Even the animation doesn't work.

Comment: Does it help to use the `touchstart` handler instead?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: @JDB No, it only works on pc.

Comment: Very strange - that should work. My guess is that there's an error somewhere on your page which is preventing any JS from loading at all, in which case none of your code is working (which might explain why the animations are failing). I've never used Brave on a mobile device... but I'd guess that it's possible to open debugging tools for it, which should help you find the error.

Comment: Yeah - here's how to attach to the debugger for Android: https://github.com/brave/browser-android-tabs#debugging

Comment: @JDB I tried now on Chrome (on Android) and it works. Even without the jQuery handler.

Comment: Yeah... sounds like there's something in your JS that Brave doesn't like. I can't really help you further, unfortunately, since I know nothing about Brave.

Comment: @JDB Thanks anyway. I think none of my clients will use brave so, relax.